# Createing a custom loop in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops

I want to create a custom loop that excludes the first 3 posts that has a certain meta value.

```
posts in base; 
1-post(meta value exist)
2-post(meta value exist)
3-post
4-post(meta value exist)
5-post
6-post
7-post(meta value exist)
8-post(meta value exist)
.
.

output will be like;

3-post
5-post
6-post
7-post(meta value exist)
8-post(meta value exist)
```

any idea?

Comment: What have you tried to do? Where is your code to loop through the posts?

Answer (score 0):

got a sollution;

```
$ids = wp_list_pluck( $previous_query->posts, 'ID'); // gets quered ids
$args = array(
   'post__not_in' => $ids
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I am not sure if this is the best way but works for me.